# SVG filter using d3 js not working in IE

Tags: d3.js, svg

im creating svg hexagaon using d3 line. i want to add shadow to it. it works in chrome but not in IE. below is a part of code.

```
container = d3.select('#' + attrs.id)
              .append('svg');

//---------------------------------------Filters-------------------
var defs = container.append("defs");

// create filter with id #drop-shadow
// height=130% so that the shadow is not clipped
var filter = defs.append("filter")
                 .attr("id", attrs.id+"drop-shadow")
                 .attr("height", "130%").attr("width", "130%");

// SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
// convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
// in blur
filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
      .attr("stdDeviation", 6)
      .attr("result", "blur");

// translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
// store result in offsetBlur
filter.append("feOffset")
      .attr("in", "blur")
      .attr("dy", 5)
      .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

// overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
// feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
       .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
       .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
container.style("filter", "url(#" + attrs.id + "drop-shadow)").attr('height', containerHeight)
         .attr('width', containerWidth + 100);
```

Comment: Please add the rest of your code to create a working example.  The problem probably isn't with your filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the bug.

i was adding filter to svg and not to the "g" element inside svg. Adding filter to "g" worked in IE for me