# d3 wrong application of a light effect to a circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, svg-filters

I am trying to apply a "feDiffuseLighting and feSpecularLighting" filter according to this tutorial: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#filters

I need the center of light moving together with the circle being drawn.

I wrote the following code with the intention that center of spotlight is the center fo the circle. But it draws the circle but it does not apply the light effect....:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){return d.x})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return d.y})
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill","white")
        .append("filter")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .append("feSpecularLighting")
        .attr("specularExponent","25")
        .attr("lighting-color","yellow")
        .append("fePointLight")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y})         
        .attr("z","8");
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper syntax for filter usage in d3. You need to add the filter element to a defs parent with an id, and then add a filter *attribute* to the circle element referring to it aka:

```
    .attr("filter","url(#light-me")
```

See other questions (e.g. [SVG filter using d3 js not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718573/svg-filter-using-d3-js-not-working-in-ie)) for proper usage